# Unrecognized content security policy directives: disown-opener, reflected-xss, referrer

Tags: content-security-policy

I'm at least 90% sure that the following is a result of Chrome's implementation of [W3C's CSP standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP/), but I thought that it'd be best to double down and make sure.

I'm currently in the process of implementing a strict content security policy for a client, and I've run into the following policy directive complications on Chrome 66:

```
Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive 'disown-opener'.
Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive 'reflected-xss'.
Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive 'referrer'.
```

Again, I'm sure this is a standards issue (as I'm using [MDN’s CSP documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy)). If this is the case, can anyone direct me to competing or substituting directives?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive 'reflected-xss'

The `reflected-xss` directive was [removed from the CSP spec](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=657737) in 2016. But you can use the [`X-XSS-Protection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-XSS-Protection) header to get exactly the same effect `reflected-xss` was meant for.

> Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive 'referrer'.

The [`referrer` directive was dropped long ago](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/referrer). Use the [`Referrer-Policy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy) header instead.

> Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive 'disown-opener'

Use [`rel=noopener`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/links.html#link-type-noopener) on any external links. It’s [supported in all modern browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=rel-noopener).